# How to efficiently find a post with WordPress-like URL info

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, kohana-3

I want to have WordPress-like URLs for my posts in my tiny CMS. I can do the route easy and get URLs like this:

```
<year>/<month>/<day>/<slug>
2012/01/31/some-post-slug
```

So from that I would get 4 pieces of information: year, month, day and the slug. In my database I have a datetime column and a column for the slug:

```
published: 2012-01-31 01:02:03
slug: some-post-slug
```

How do I create a good database index and a good query, using my 4 pieces of information, to find posts efficiently?

***Note:** The Kohana 3 tag is just if someone has some specific tips for that, since that's what I'm using. Still interested in PHP/MySQL answers as well.*

Answer (score 3):

Make another column called `permalink` and put computed value ("2012/01/31/some-post-slug") there. Put an index on it and you're good to go.

It's as efficient (and simple) as it can get. :-)

Comment: *face-palm* Now that is a simple a solution indeed. Still curious on how to do this in other ways, but this is probably what I'll end up doing, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Generate your urls using article ID (`<year>/<month>/<day>/<id>-<slug>`
), like `2012/01/31/123-some-post-slug`.

PS. Just another way, not so good as Sergio's ;)

Comment: Yeah, been thinking of doing that too, kind of like they do it here at SO. Also definitely a good idea as I would have the id to look up with.